# angular 2 - splice array and observables

Tags: arrays, angular, observable

I've created a form with angular 2...I have a function that returns me an array of object

```
public getList( ){
return this.http.get(`${APPCONSTANTS.API_PATH}/list/`)
  .map(res => <myType[]> res.json())
  .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        return Observable.throw(error);
    });}
```

which fills 2 arrays declared in the class

```
export class ContestAdmComponent {

public firstArray [] = [];
public secondArray[] = [];

test(){
this.myService.getList()
    .subscribe(
        _data => {
            this.firstArray = _data;
            this.secondArray= _data;
        },
        e => console.log('onError: %s', e),
        () => console.log('onCompleted')
    );
 }
```

}

Now I have to empty first array (it was modified by UI) and refills it with the second one, but when I delete firstArray also secondArray becomes empty

```
private testDelete(){
    console.log('pre delete : ' + this.secondArray.length)
    this.firstArray .splice(0,this.firstArray.length);
    console.log('post delete : ' + this.secondArray.length)
 }
```

pre delete : 154
post delete : 0

I think this behaviuor concerns observable...but i've no idea

thanks in advance

Comment: No, it's not because of observables, but because of JS semantics: FirstArray and SecondArray are "pointing" to the same array, so when you make changes to one, it will reflect on the other. You have to create a copy of that array when assigning it.... there are many methods, fastest: `this.firstArray = _data.concat([])`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments by olivarra1, you are assigning `_data` to both arrays. This means both the arrays will operate on the same object.

One solution is to use concat.

```
this.firstArray = _data.concat([])
```